# Setup for a secure encrypted distro on stick?

Tags: linux, encryption, usb-drive, live-usb

I recently bought a SSD USB "Stick" - I think it qualifies as drive as it has 256GB.

I want to set it up so that:

- It can boot a linux from (almost) any machine (if so configured)
- Data is encrypted
- I can access its *data* from any machine (of course only knowing it's decryption key)
- Optionally an un-encrypted space for fast data copy/sharing. This is really not important but could be useful.

How would I go about such a project?

I'd rather not want to use `tails` as it uses Tor per default, making everything slow I'd assume. Rather I'd want to optionally use secure communications manually (e.g. tor-browser) if I need to.

I usually run `manjaro`, but I am not sure I want a rolling distro for this, as the drive would become outdated quickly and I don't want to have to update it all the time.

Comment: Pretty much any modern popular distro allows that. The only difficulty is that there are still MBR PCs around and if you use EFI partitioning and boot, you will not be able to boot on a pre EFI PC.

Comment: I should maybe clarify that I would want to access its data / write to it without having to boot from it, .e.g. write data to it / read data from it from my manjaro work machine

Comment: That's perfectly possible as well.